# jQuery animate on click multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am currently building a web app where I need to randomly generate text content and switch its color every time a button is clicked.

At the moment, I'm trying to add some kind of animation to it, and here's what I'd like to obtain each time the button is clicked:

1. The random class is added
2. The div pops up from the bottom of the page with its opacity increasing

I prepared a simplified JSFiddle to illustrate my point below.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/cdacx0tn/11/

```
var color = ["blue", "purple", "green"];

$("#try-me").click(function() { 
    var colorClass = color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];

    $("#content")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass(colorClass)
    .animate({
        "margin-top": "50px",
        "opacity": "1"
    }, 700);
});
```

I managed to get this done when the button is clicked once but I can't figure out how to do this **each time** it is clicked.

I want to add that I'm not a professional developper so please be indulgent.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the CSS of the element before animating it, making sure it's back at it's initial position with `marginTop` and can't be seen using `opacity`.

Add a `stop()` in their to prevent animations being queued and there you have it:

```
var color = ["blue", "purple", "green"];

$("#try-me").click(function() { 
    var colorClass = color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
    $("#content")
        .css({opacity:0,marginTop:200})
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(colorClass)
        .stop(true,false)
        .animate({
            "margin-top": "50px",
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 700);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdacx0tn/10/)

**Documentation:**

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
- [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Simple and nice, it works like a charm. Thanks for your help, and the stop() tip!

Comment: @morgi No problem, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 var color = ["blue", "purple", "green"];

    $("#try-me").click(function() { 
        var colorClass = color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
        $("#content").css({ "margin-top": "200px", "opacity": "0"});  // reset the margin and opacity value
        $("#content")
        .removeClass()
        .addClass(colorClass)
        .animate({
            "margin-top": "50px",
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 700,function(){


        });
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/cdacx0tn/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Re initialize the `margin-top` of `#content` to `200px` after animation :

```
     $("#content").css("margin-top","200px");
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdacx0tn/13/)