# jquery animate() color multiple times, every 5 seconds, then loop/restart

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-animate, delay

I am new to coding my own jQuery. I've loaded jQuery and the [jQuery color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) and have managed a simple color animate after a 5 second delay, with a 1 second transition:

```
$("h1").delay(5000).animate({
    color: "blue"
}, 1000 );
```

What I am trying to do next is change the color again and again, every 5 seconds (blue, green, red, pink, orange) and then have that cycle continue over and over without stopping.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283571/jquery-animate-on-click-multiple-times) that was somewhat helpful in showing that the colors can be set in a variable but I'm not sure where to go from there and have the cycle start over when it's done.

Any help and/or links would be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uudtds79/

Comment: Or slightly shorter http://jsfiddle.net/uudtds79/1/

Comment: thanks cheery- the first one seems to work but has a few lines of code I can't decipher what they are doing. The second fiddle only changes to the first color in the array and then stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0urbkqs/3/)

```
var c = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'olive', 'yellow']
    if (c > colors.length - 1) c = 0;
    $("h1").animate({
        color: colors[c++]
    }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

CSS solution for this would be:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0urbkqs/5/)

```
h1 {
    animation: colorChanger 60s infinite;
    -moz-animation: colorChanger 60s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: colorChanger 60s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes colorChanger {
    from {
        color: blue;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    20% {
        color: green;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    40% {
        color: red;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    60% {
        color: olive;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    80% {
        color: yellow;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    to {
        color: brown;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes colorChanger {
    from {
        color: blue;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    20% {
        color: green;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    40% {
        color: red;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    60% {
        color: olive;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    80% {
        color: yellow;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
    to {
        color: brown;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I need the colors to be fired in order, though, not random.

Comment: Hmmm...when I click the link and the Fiddle loads I wait 10 seconds and nothing happens. I tried clicking RUN too and nothing happens.

Comment: I got your code to work outside of jfiddle, and had to add "++" to line 6 (I noticed you had that in the 1st fiddle). I can't use CSS animation because it doesn't work with some other javascript I'm using (wow.js). Would you be able to do a code change to have it work with switchClass() instead of animate() and I could put the class names in the variable array instead?

Comment: Yes I could but it won't animate. It will change the color instantly.

Comment: oh, switchClass() is not animate-able? If I can define the colors in CSS that would be better for my situation - I am using SCSS variables. Also, I need to change the fill property on an SVG and that does not work with animate.